# Package acmart doesn't show author name

Tags: acmart

My name doesn't print when using ACM's acmart package.  Here is my code

```
%File: formatting-instruction.tex
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\setcopyright{acmcopyright}
\copyrightyear{2021}
\acmYear{2021}
\acmDOI{10.1145/1122445.1122456}

\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} % Allows to place the legend below plot
\usepgfplotslibrary{units} % Allows to enter the units nicely

\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\bbone}{\text{\usefont{U}{bbold}{m}{n}1}}

\DeclareMathOperator{\EX}{\mathbb{E}}% expected value






\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{helvet}
\bibliography{Research_Paper}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\frenchspacing
\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{8.5in}
\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{11in}
\author{ABC}
\email{abc@abc.edu}

\affiliation{%
  \institution{Institution}
  \streetaddress{Address}
  \city{City}
  \state{State}
  \country{USA}
  \postcode{51234}
}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}  
\title{Stuff researchers do in their busy time}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\begin{quote}
Stuff
\end{quote}
\end{abstract}

 Why doesn't my name print?
\end{document}
```

Comment: This appears to be related to the use of the `authblk` package in combination with the `acmart` class. What do you want to use that package for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ACM commissioned Boris Veytsman with the task of producing a LaTeX document class for its publications and has, as far as I know, officially endorsed it.

You should not use font packages with the class, for instance, so papers will be uniform in appearance. If you don't like the font used by the class, don't use `acmart`; if you must use it because you're making a submission, comply with the editors' requirements of not changing fonts.

The class has several facilities for typesetting authors and affiliations thereof. The `authblck` package is *not* compatible with it and should not be loaded.

Other small notes. The `quote` environment should not be used in the abstract and the abstract must go before `\maketitle`.

Here's an edited version of your document, with some packages commented out for better clarity. Remove the lines.

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}

% Packages
%\usepackage{authblk} % NOT with acmart
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units} % Allows to enter the units nicely
%\usepackage{filecontents} % OBSOLETE
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[section]{placeins} % dubious
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{times} % NOT with acmart
%\usepackage{helvet} % NOT with acmart
%\usepackage{courier} % NOT with acmart
\usepackage{amsmath}

% settings
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} % Allows to place the legend below plot
%\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{8.5in} % NOT with acmart
%\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{11in}  % NOT with acmart
\frenchspacing

% personal commands
\DeclareRobustCommand{\bbone}{\text{\usefont{U}{bbold}{m}{n}1}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\EX}{\mathbb{E}}% expected value

% metadata
\bibliography{Research_Paper}

\setcopyright{acmcopyright}
\copyrightyear{2021}
\acmYear{2021}
\acmDOI{10.1145/1122445.1122456}

\author{ABC}
\email{abc@abc.edu}

\affiliation{%
  \institution{Institution}
  \streetaddress{Address}
  \city{City}
  \state{State}
  \country{USA}
  \postcode{51234}
}
\title{Stuff researchers do in their busy time}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
Stuff
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

Why doesn't my name print?

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This detailed answer is highly appreciated